# Not able to invoke jQuery Ajax method for fileupload input value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to invoke the serverside method from the jQuery. It is working fine in Firefox but not in IE8 and IE9.

Please find the below code sample :

```
 <div>  
    <asp:FileUpload ID="flAppIcon" runat="server" onchange="GetFileSize();"/>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="_hdnAppIcon" runat="server" Value="0" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function GetFileSize() {
        var PageURL = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/WebForm16.aspx") %>'
        var test = ($('#<%=flAppIcon.ClientID%>').val()).toString();
        $("#<%=_hdnAppIcon.ClientID%>").val(test);
        alert($("#<%=_hdnAppIcon.ClientID%>").val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: PageURL + '/GetFileSizeDetails',
            data: '{file: "' + $("#<%=_hdnAppIcon.ClientID%>")[0].value + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
</script> 

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetFileSizeDetails(string file)
{
    return "100";
}
```

Can anyone help me to know the root cause of this issue?

Thanks & regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Comment: I'm not familiar with the server side language you are usuing, but typically you need your server side function to actually PRINT a value, not just return it.

Comment: Check out what `$("#<%=_hdnAppIcon.ClientID%>")[0].value` is returning

It has format `C:\fakepath\your-file.jpg` so that won't send over nicely via a webmethod

Answer (score 0):

Since `$("#<%=_hdnAppIcon.ClientID%>")[0].value` has the format: `C:\fakepath\your-file.jpg`, it will not be valid JSON when it goes over to the server side via the WebMethod

You're selecting the file path instead of the size.  Based on your function name, I'm assuming you want the file size sent back to the server.

Try using

```
$("#<%=_hdnAppIcon.ClientID%>")[0].files[0].size
```

instead of

```
$("#<%=_hdnAppIcon.ClientID%>")[0].value
```

Comment: I was trying to get the filesize of the uploaded file using jquery. But it worked fine in Firefox and not in IE9. It required ActiveX object creation which was not possible for me to ask every end user to enable the ActiveX object in IE9 browser. Hence I thought of passing the file from the client side and getting the file size in server side code which didn't worked for me in IE9,8.

Comment: I did some research. Apparently this method is using the HTML5 API, so it is not supported in any version of IE yet.  Since ActiveX is out of the question, the only other way would be to use Flash